# I need to install Oracle XE 11g on Debian 8, how?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, server, debian, vps

How can I install Oracle on Debian 8, I try a lot of solution but I had an error on 
`sudo service procps start`

please complete the instructions?

Comment: What error do you get? If you expect people to help you need to provide sufficient information for them to understand what's gone wrong.

Comment: thanks, i get this error: Failed to write '6815744' to '/proc/sys/fs/file-max': Permission denied nov. 16 00:13:46 vps45339 systemd-sysctl[25345]: Failed to write '9000 65000' to '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range': Permission denied nov. 16 00:13:46 vps45339 systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE nov. 16 00:13:46 vps45339 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables.

Comment: I'm following this [tutorial](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.de/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your prerequisites correctly?
Debian isn't a supported linux distribution to run oracle on, so you can get this working, but you will have to put all your prerequisites manually.

Comment: Please can you help me with exist tutorial link?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is not supported on debian. You might get it working by performing the prerequisites stuff correctly.  You can find them here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#CIHFICFD